# Blur Node (compositing)

Tags: blur

When I plug mask image into **Size input** of **Blur node** in the result get equal Blurriness across the whole image, why is it happening? Reading form manual "*The optional Size input will be multiplied with the X and Y blur radius values. It also accepts a value image, to control the blur radius with a mask. The values should be mapped between (0 to 1) for an optimal effect*". I anticipate to get a vague image merely where is a white color. What is wrong here?
[image]

Comment: Can you share your blend file?

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka Not necessary, just a tick needs to be made in the Blur node, see my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to check *Variable Size* in the *Blur* node. Hovering your mouse over it you can see it says: "Support variable blur per pixel when using an image for size input." But note that the boundary of the mask image also gets blurred, there's no sharp transition between blurred and unblurred image.

[image: blur mask]

Comment: You're right, I tried with a Fast Gaussian which didn't have that option so I was completely oblivious to it.

Comment: Ah, done great thank you! Should be default

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka Yea, Fast Gaussian doesn't have the option

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka Yeah, I usually use Fast Gaussian as well, but that's the advantage of having screenshots... then a file is often not necessary ;)